# How can a client handle data that comes from a stream faster than it can be processed? - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to stream market data from my broker and all the examples I've seen handle one item at a time. However, what happens if it takes 200ms to process an item but the stream is delivering items every 50ms? The market data would increasingly become out of sync and irrelevant, correct? I imagine this is a common problem for many applications and I'm amazed I couldn't find anything on this topic with my searches. How do people deal with this in Python? Threading? Also, I don't understand why all the examples I've seen don't have a process in place to handle this possibility; do people just assume they can process faster than the data stream and therefore only process one item at a time?

I just want to ensure my script will be using the latest market data as that's critical when making trades. I'm quite inexperienced with streaming, WebSockets, asyncio, threading, so whatever information you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

If necessary, my current code in its basic form is as follows:

```
async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
    await websocket.send(payload)

    while True:
        response = await websocket.recv()

        # Process response
```

Comment: Generally speaking, if your process is data crunching aka cpu bound, then multiprocessing would help. But in the case where your process is to write to file, send to network, aka IO bound, then creating threads will help. I recommend creating a multiprocessing pool and submit the jobs.

Comment: Generally speaking a queue-worker architecture is useful here. The thing processing incoming messages only needs to shunt them into a message queue as fast as possible; from there, multiple workers can handle the queue and take their time processing each message. The number of workers can be scaled as necessary, even automatically depending on queue backlog. This can take many forms, from multi-threading to distributed workers on separate machines.

Comment: Thank you both for the responses, @thu-yein-tun. Can async be used for this at all? Or is it better to use threads/processes? I'm not quite sure on if it would be CPU or I/O bound. Each item goes through some conditionals, logging is done, and occasionally data is written to a database. I believe this would be considered I/O bound?

Comment: @auxi If there's no computation, then you can consider it I/O bound. You can find out if it is I/O or CPU bound by checking `top` or `htop` while running the process, does it take up too much CPU or too much I/O. Recently I read an article about [async io vs thread benchmark](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-better-way-for-asynchronous-programming-asyncio-over-multi-threading-3457d82b3295) asyncio looks to be about 4 times faster than threads in that case.

Comment: _I just want to ensure my script will be using the latest market data as that's critical when making trades._ It's not directly related to your question, but I hope you're not trading using real money, or at least not much. Be careful :)

Comment: @AMC I absolutely am using real money! :D However, I am not doing anything crazy; I'm simply setting it up to how I've been manually trading for years. Also, these are relatively low risk strategies, so I should be okay! I will be doing dry runs for a few weeks too, to iron out any bugs and such. Thank you and you too if you are involved in the markets! These are difficult times, even for many proven strategies.

Comment: _However, I am not doing anything crazy; I'm simply setting it up to how I've been manually trading for years._ That makes sense, I was just checking because you occasionally see people trying to get into what is essentially HFT using Python from their home computer, which can't possibly end well. Is this something you do professionally?

Comment: @AMC Absolutely, I completely agree. I do not do HFT, nor would I ever. IMO, HFT only really works for large firms, not retail traders. But that's the hot topic these days, many young programmers think they can beat the markets with ML and HFT, some may, many will not. It's unfortunate to see people lose their life savings pursuing these ideas. I don't do this professionally, but have been doing it since the day I turned 18 and now manage friend's/family's accounts. So in a sense you could say I do it "professionally", but on the side of my day job.